# activating conda environment within slurm bash script

Tags: bash, anaconda, slurm

I am trying to run nanoplot on a computing node via Slurm by loading a conda environment installed in the group_home directory. I have all required packages installed on the environment located in group_home directory. (the Anaconda3 is installed in my home directory but as I ran out of space, I created envs and pkgs on group_home and installed all packages for nanoplot there).
Here is how my script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -l
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# SLURM script for nanopack long read QC
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#SBATCH --job-name==nanopack
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=5G
#SBATCH --tasks=1
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=XX
#SBATCH --partition=XX
#SBATCH --export=ALL

source /home/users/anna/.bashrc
source activate /home/users/anna/st/envs/longqc



## Directories:
# Locate the input data
ROOT_DIR=/groups/st/analysis/anna/longreads/
FASQ_DIR=${ROOT_DIR}/nanopore1/fastq


# Output directory
OUTPUT_DIR=${ROOT_DIR}/nanopore1/summary_plot

## Input file

FAStQ=${FASQ_DIR}/both.fastq.gz

Nanoplot --fastq ${FAStQ} -o ${OUTPUT_DIR} -t $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
```

I already looked at some other posts sharing a similar issue and tried to test all possible solutions but still no success. One thing is that I am trying to run the script on the computing node and not on a log in node. but it seems my script cannot load the packet as may Jon fails due to `"/var/spool/slurmd/job16013739/slurm_script: line 37: Nanoplot: command not found"` . I am not sure what I can do or what I am missing to fix this issue and get my script running. I repay appreciate if I could get some help here to sort this issue out. Thanks

I tried `conda activate /home/users/anna/st/envs/longqc`
as well but the same error shows up.

Comment: are you able to run `Nanoplot` installed in the group_home from your login node?

Comment: if you can use the `Nanoplot` from the login node, it should work in the compute node. I would suggest you to add `which python`  before and after activating the conda env. This will confirm if the conda env is activated or not.